# Equivalence Clasess modulo n to and exponential

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know that for an equivalence class $$[a]^{[b]_{\phi(m)}}$$ to be well defined, be must be an equivalence class of $\phi(m)$.  However, can we always assume that $$[a]^{[b+c]}= [a]^{[b]_{\phi(m)}}[a]^{[c]_{\phi(m)}}$$ 
And why is that?